# TimeSpan в GridControl от DevExpress

Tags: c#, datetime, devexpress

В компоненте от DevExpress `gridControl` есть возможность промежуточных итогов.
Если формат ячейки `TimeSpan` то при суммировании прибавляются дни, то есть не `145:15` (145 часов 15 минут), а `6.1:15` (6 дней 1 час 15 минут).

Kакой `StringFormat` задать что бы было вот так `145:15` (145 часов 15 минут)???

Answer (score 1):

`TimeSpan` не реализует интерфейс `IFormatProvider`. По этому вам надо [вручную отформатировать это значение](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114633) или можете исползовать тип `DateTime` для ячейки.

Ваш вопрос в DevExpress:

1. [Formatting time (TimeSpan) summary values. FormatString does not work](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q318527/formatting-time-timespan-summary-values-formatstring-does-not-work)
2. [timespan
   format](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B190093/timespan-format)
3. [FormatString doesn't work as
   expected](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B20589/formatstring-doesn-t-work-as-expected)